# Sci-fi anime with two protagonists that lead (opposing) armies in space

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw a preview/trailer of an anime that had two main protagonists, both the leaders of armies/troops that fight each other in space.

The first protagonist has blonde hair, is a genius in war and is from noble family (maybe). The second protagonist has black hair, is also genius in war and wears a beret or painter's hat.

I saw this trailer recently (maybe from last year?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds a lot like the OVA series [Legend of the Galactic Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Galactic_Heroes), particularly the description of the two men. The blond would be Reinhard von Müsel/Lohengramm while the black-haired guy would be Yang Wen Li. It was originally produced in the 80s-90s but is being remade; you likely saw a trailer for the remake.

[image: Advertisement image from Wikipedia featuring Reinhard and Yang: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LoGH_Overture_to_a_New_War.jpg]

Official website (in Japanese), if you're interested: http://www.ginei.jp/